# Inverse of symbolic hyperbolic function

Tags: symbolic, special-functions, inverse-function

I have a function

$$u = 1/4*\cosh(x)^2$$

Entered in Mathematica as

```
1/4*Cosh[x]^2
```

Inverted using

```
InverseFunction[1/4*Cosh[x]^2][x]
```

Why is it that Mathematica returns:

```
InverseFunction[Cosh[x]^2/4][x]
```

Instead of

$$x = \cosh^{-1}(-2\sqrt{u})$$

Essentially, Mathematica can't parse this and returns my input for some reason. How do I invert this symbolic expression?

Comment: I suspect it is because the function is squared. So it is multivalued. So has no inverse function.

Comment: Following the documentation, try `InverseFunction[1/4*Cosh[#]^2 &]`.

Comment: Try `Solve[1/4*Cosh[x]^2 == u, x, Reals]`.

Comment: @b.gates.youknow.what: This produces "InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses." and an incorrect result.

Comment: @user64494 this is entirely expected - look in [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) in the _Possible issues_ section.  The result is correct insofar as `f[g[x]] == x` where `f = 1/4*Cosh[#]^2 &; g = InverseFunction[1/4*Cosh[#]^2 &];` but `g[f[x]]` will not give `x`

Comment: Solve[y == 1/4 Cosh[x]^2, x] will get you all solutions